# Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getBattery is not a function .Error while developing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Badge Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "scripting",
    "background"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Badge Extension</title>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
navigator.getBattery().then((battery) => {
  updateBatteryStatus(battery);
  battery.onlevelchange = function () {
    updateBatteryStatus(battery);
  };
  battery.onchargingchange = function () {
    updateBatteryStatus(battery);
  };
});
```

I received two error messages
1.Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
2.Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getBattery is not a function[[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnapZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0pwn.png)

I want to get rid this error.I think that this error is regard with manifest version3.Please solve this error

Comment: As the error says you can't use this function in a service worker. You can do it in the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). P.S. Don't load background.js in the popup. Make a different popup.js

Comment: thanks.I will try with offscreen document